# rendering part of a large list smoothly with Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm looking for a way to smoothly render a large "part" of the list.
The list is huge now 1.000 items.(test set) I've figured out that the rendering of this list takes the most time. Not the sorting and filtering I'm doing on it.
When I render/view the entire list at once the browser locks until it's done.

What can I do to speed up the rendering?

Should I use pagination? Is there a way to smoothly scroll over the list, and only render part of the list that is visible. what events should i listen to? example code?

Comment: Am am looking for a similar thing and have yet to find an answer. Here is a link (http://jsbin.com/ulukep/26/edit) to an an example of a large list filtering. I hacked it together from another search/filter example I found, btw.

Comment: Bonus points if it uses https://github.com/emberjs/list-view :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to comment instead of answering, but I don't have the rep for that (which seems backwards). Anyway,

First, Define "huge" list. How many rows?

Second, define "render". Do you just need to spit out the HTML as fast as possible, or do you need to generate a data-bound view?

In my experience, the fastest way to generate HTML is to push strings to an array, e.g.

```
var s=""; 
s.push("<table.."); 
$(body).append(s.join("")).
```

So if you want maximum performance, this is the way to go. You can use this technique with an ember view by simply overriding the render() method. Of course, you lose data binding, which is the coolest part of ember. If you need data binding, but only on a few fields, you might be able to improve performance to a satisfactory level by turning off data binding where it's not needed with the unbound helper:

```
{{unbound myfield}}
```

Comment: I definitely need the bindings. I fixed it now by building a paginator mixin, and some simple paginate views which shows the list in blocks of 50, (enough to fill the screen) now everything is snappy again.

Comment: @Stephan can you share how you did the block-wise rendering? How did you tell ember to render those paginate views one by one?

Comment: I have a controller with a visible array. Sorts, filtering, pagination  etc change the contents of the vissible array. The visible array is constructed from the 1000+ item contents array which is not visualized / rendered. It works very smooth this way.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time on this problem and the best answer I've found is to dynamically load list items as they are scrolled to.

[ember-list-view](https://github.com/emberjs/list-view) for lists

[ember-table](https://github.com/Addepar/ember-table) for tables

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add filtering and sorting to the table as well. And I created a subset of the large array. visible. that is 'duh' vissible on the screen. It only has 50 rows or so and that's very fast. Rendering 1000 or more rows all at once is stupid anyway. NOTE Using {{unbound myfield}} helps a lot.

So the sorts and filters are done on the large not rendereed array. When sort and filter action's are done on the big array the visible array get's updated with a small subset. this works smooth.

There are by now ton's of examples of fast table views.

Comment: Have you found any examples that you can link to?